# SAAJ insert two prefix in one local part

Tags: prefix, saaj

I need to insert 2 prefix for one local part. In SAAJ I did

```
QName bodyName = new QName(url,"local1", "prefix1");
```

I need another prefix in same body name. It should look like this:

```
<prefix1:local1 xmlns:prefix1=”url1” 
xmlns:prefix2="url2">
```

Could someone point me to right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

```
SOAPBodyElement bodyElement;
bodyElement.addNamespaceDeclaration("prefix2", "url2");
```